# Which one is better for creating a follower-following system, Foreign Key or ManyToMany in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Which one would be optimal for creating the followers-following system in Django.

1.Foreign Key

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='following')
    following_id    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='followers')
```

2.Many-To-Many

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='following')
    followers        = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

So, for instance, if we want to retrive the following list of the user:
1.Foreign Key

```
Follower.objects.get(following_id=1).following.all()
```

2 Many-To-Many

```
User.object.get(user=1).follower_set.all().values('current_user')
```

Comment: Option 1 is in essence what a `ManyToManyField` from user to itself would do. Your second option uses a `ManyToManyField` but it introduces a useless intermediate table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add metadata about someone following you don't have much choice but to use a M2M with a through table. Otherwise, you might as well use option 1.